# Using indexes to get the sum of all the elements in an array list gives unexpected output. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a folder that contains four files. Each of the four files contains an integer. My code reads the integers from the files into an ArrayList.

```
       // Reading the save data.
       File[] fileArray = SaveData.listFiles();
       ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

       // For each file in the file array
       for (File file2 : fileArray ) {
              FileReader fr = new FileReader(file2);
              al.add (fr.read());
              System.out.println(al); }
```

The code works. The data from the files are successfully read into an ArrayList. The problem is when I am trying to sum all the elements of the array list.

```
       int i;
       for(i = 1; i < al.size(); i++) {
       Integer sum = 0;
       sum += al.get(i);
       System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

The code shows this output:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 3]
The sum is: 1
The sum is: 3
The sum is: 3
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 7):

You've declared `sum` *inside* your loop - so you're starting again on each iteration. You want:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
   sum += al.get(i);
}
System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

Note that:

- I've changed `sum` to be an `int` rather than an `Integer`; there's no need to use `Integer` here [When to use Int vs Integer](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/08/java-int-versus-integer.html)
- I've changed the lower bound the loop to 0 instead of 1
- You could still use an enhanced loop if you want... (I normally would)
- With Java 8 you could use streams to make it simpler still

Answer (score 2):

Well for one you're starting from `i = 1` instead of the correct `i = 0`.
You're also reinitializing the `sum` every time in the loop.